# How to manipulate the legend height

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't work out how to automatically the size of my legend. I know you can do axis manipulation with theme(axis...) but I can't find the correct argument to pass!

I tried:

- theme(
  legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
  legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm")
  )

Sample code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=date) )+ 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=temperature))+
  scale_x_time(breaks = hms::hms(hours = seq(0, 24, 4))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="red") +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x="", y ="", fill="Temperature", title="")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=14), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=14),
        strip.text = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))+
   theme(
    legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
    legend.key.height = unit(4, "cm")
  )
```

Sample data:

```
 df<-structure(list(time = structure(c(63285, 63885, 64485, 65085, 
65685, 66285, 66885, 67485, 68085, 68685, 69285, 69885, 70485, 
71085, 71685, 72285, 72885, 73485, 74085, 74685, 75285, 75885, 
76485, 77085, 77685, 78285, 78885, 79485, 80085, 80685, 81285, 
81885, 82485, 83085, 83685, 84285, 84885, 85485, 86085, 285, 
885, 1485, 2085, 2685, 3285, 3885, 4485, 5085, 5685, 6285), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), temperature = c(6.31, 14.81, 17.13, 
16.56, 16.44, 16.44, 16.56, 16.69, 16.88, 17, 17.13, 17.19, 17.31, 
17.5, 17.81, 18.06, 18.19, 18.25, 18.25, 18.19, 18.06, 17.94, 
17.81, 17.75, 17.63, 17.5, 17.44, 17.38, 17.25, 17.19, 17.13, 
17.06, 17, 17, 16.88, 16.88, 16.88, 16.81, 16.81, 16.81, 16.81, 
16.88, 16.88, 16.88, 16.88, 16.88, 16.81, 16.81, 16.81, 16.75
), humidity = c(0.674, 0.643, 0.472, 0.503, 0.515, 0.523, 0.53, 
0.539, 0.541, 0.546, 0.548, 0.549, 0.555, 0.561, 0.578, 0.577, 
0.575, 0.579, 0.596, 0.597, 0.599, 0.604, 0.612, 0.616, 0.619, 
0.623, 0.637, 0.638, 0.639, 0.639, 0.643, 0.646, 0.649, 0.653, 
0.654, 0.66, 0.664, 0.668, 0.672, 0.676, 0.691, 0.693, 0.693, 
0.694, 0.693, 0.694, 0.698, 0.691, 0.694, 0.697), date = c("04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
"04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "05/01/2022", "05/01/2022", 
"05/01/2022", "05/01/2022", "05/01/2022", "05/01/2022", "05/01/2022", 
"05/01/2022", "05/01/2022", "05/01/2022", "05/01/2022")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: I get "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" when I try to run your code.

Comment: The example data doesn't work with the code. The temperature is class of character.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, and the `legend.key.height` and `legend.key.width` arguments affect the legend.  (They apply to single entries, not the whole legend, so the height should be 1cm to make the legend 4cm high.)